# How can I quickly discharge a capacitor in a Zener on-delay timer circuit?

Tags: capacitor, zener, delay, discharge, latching

I have a project that requires using a delayed latching circuit. I found two circuits that I could combine, a on-delay timer circuit from TheEngineeringMindset and a latching circuit from CircuitDigest.

In this combined circuit, the switch for the delay circuit would be a 5V logic signal, the Zener diode's anode would be connected to the latching circuits input, and the latching circuit input would be powered by 24V (since I'm using a 24V relay.)

Is there a way for the capacitor in the delay circuit to be quickly discharged when the logic signal is LOW?

Here are the circuits for reference.

Additional question: What do you think would be good values for the resistors, capacitor and Zener diode?

I already have initial values for them, but the time delay is still quite short, I'm looking for 3-5 second delay: top resistor = 10k, bottom resistor = 10M, elec.cap = 220uf 6.3v, Zener voltage = 2.7V

EDIT: The circuit is for detecting "fault" signal/s in the system I'm designing, and the latching circuit works, I just added a 10k from the input pin to GND.

[image: on delay timer circuit]

[image]

Comment: The circuit expects a HIGH signal for 3 or 5s before triggering the alarm. This alarm is for detecting "fault" signal in the system I'm designing

Comment: To turn off the alarm, the base of Q1 in the latching circuit needs to be shorted to GND as what CircuitDigest says

Answer (score 1):

Not clear you want to do.

[image]

Your second circuit should not function as you want.
Should change your R1=100k -> 1k  (my R4).

Delay can be added at the input with a discharge path through MOSFET.(will add later).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One part of your question is, how to fast discharge a capacitor when the charge source is turned off. This circuit can be used up to 5 V supply. The limit is defined by the maximum allowed base - emitter reverse voltage, 5-6 V is a typical value. The B/E breakdown would fast charge C1 via R2.

C1 is not fully discharged this way, around 0.6V will remain, the base - emitter forward voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuL5cr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>